# How can I add my MERN website sitemap to Google search console

Tags: mern, sitemap

Hi I have a mern website which is hosted on vps and I want to add my website's xml sitemap to Google search console. I downloaded the sitemap of my website and now I don't know what to do with it. Please guide me i am just a beginner. I searched YouTube video they are only telling how to do this in WordPress

I have downloaded the XML sitemap of my website just don't  know where to put it